# How to create single page and render many pages in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

i want to create an ASP.NET website, what i want to do is to create a page lets name it the main page "main.aspx", not MVC or razor pages.

Then inside this page i control and render the other pages using paramter in the url named "method" for example as following :

main.aspx?method=register : so the register page or view rendered in the main page.

main.aspx?method=users : the users page or view rendered in the main page.

My question is, what it the right choice to do this in Visual studio 2017 ?

if web forms is the right one, what is the main page should be "Default.aspx" or another page ? where i should exactly get the "method" value ? where i should put the template or the view of the "register" for example? and what is the expected content to be inside it ?

Comment: Why do you wish to do it this way?

Comment: It's just and idea, want to know how this way can be implemented

Comment: I don't think it's a good architecture. It will end with difficult maintenance and, depending on the website size, complex code, hard to read. I suggest you to implement a URL rewrite solution and manage the page call accordingly (i.e.: register-user, view-users...)

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds like* you want a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) type of site.

> My question is, what it the right choice to do this in Visual studio 2017 ?

Sure it is, if you understand what you are building. Try creating a new ASP.NET Core project with the SPA template, and see if that is what you are looking for. If so,  I would strongly suggest checking out the [ASP.NET SPA Documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webforms, the template that can wrap other pages is called a MasterPage.

You don't need to pass the page name through a querystring, though. You can accomplish that with the URL Rewrite module or with Routing, but neither is necessary. The MasterPage will wrap any page that uses it automatically.

Here's an overview:

ASP.NET Master Pages

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx